# Print out days under correct weekday title

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I'm trying to print out a calendar.

I have an array of all the days in a month (date objects). I was thinking of creating a table with the weekdays (mon, tue, ...) in the `<thead>` and printing out each day in the `<tbody>` (this means that each row has 7 data cells).

My question is, how can I make sure that each Monday is printed under the correct table header? So when my month starts on a Tuesday, I want the cell on Monday to be empty.

I'm stuck on this, and I couldn't find any solution for this problem.

Here are the variables which might give you a clearer view of what I want to do

```
public currentDate: moment.Moment; /* Today */
public currentMonth: Date[] = []; /* Aray with all the dateobjects of the month */
public weekDays: string[] = []; /* week day titles */
```

**Template**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <ng-template ngFor let-weekday [ngForOf]="weekDays" let-i="index">
                <th>{{ weekday }}</th>
            </ng-template>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!--Stuck on this step-->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can't you use a freely available plugin? or your requirement is to create a one from scratch with angular?

Comment: @Harshakj89 yes, I need to create a calendar with some functionalities in material design. CTRL + CLICK = select multiple dates, CLICK + DRAG = select date range, CLICK = select date. I haven't found anything like this yet as an npm package

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript method

```
getDay()
```

To return the number of the day 0 to 6 (Sun to Sat).

You can use this to calculate the offset you need to add to start in the correct place in the table

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

First, create the first date of the month you need. Then use getDay() to find out which date of the week.

```
//January is month 0 and December in month 11.
//0 means Sunday and 6 means Saturday

var d = new Date(2017, 10, 1);
console.log(d.getDay());
```

The output of the above code is 3. That means 1st of November in 2017 is a Wednesday.